# Customizing IRB output

Tags: ruby, irb, inspect

I've created a class called SpecialArray and I'd like to customize what sort of output irb shows.  Currently, when I create a new instance of the class, irb returns the entire object.  This is what I currently see:

```
1.9.3p194 :022 > SpecialArray.new([1,2,0,6,2,11]) 
=> #<UniqueArray:0x007ff05b026ec8 @input=[1, 2, 0, 6, 2, 11], @output=[1, 2, 0, 6, 11]>
```

But I'd like to only show what I've defined as output.  In other words, I'd like to see this.

```
1.9.3p194 :022 > SpecialArray.new([1,2,0,6,2,11]) 
=> [1, 2, 0, 6, 11]
```

What do I need to do specify that irb should only display the output?

SOLUTION:

This is the method that I ended up creating.

```
def inspect
  output.inspect
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IRB calls [`Object#inspect`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-inspect) method to get string representation of your object. All you need is to override this method like that:

```
class Foo
  def inspect
    "foo:#{object_id}"
  end
end
```

Then in the IRB you'll get:

```
>> Foo.new
=> foo:70250368430260
```

In your particular case just make `SpecialArray#inspect` return string representation of the underlying array, e.g.:

```
SpecialArray
  def inspect
    @output.inspect
  end
end
```